# <body> background-color property doesn't work correctly with HTML5 DOCTYPE

Tags: css, html, doctype

So I've got a basic 2-column HTML layout that I've applied some basic CSS to:

```
html {
  background-color: gray;
}

body {
  width: 900px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo, .nav, .contact {
  float: left;
  width: 248px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.about, .banner, .content {
  float: right;
  width: 648px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

The problem is, the when I add the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration to the beginning of my page, the `background-color` attribute doesn't work for the `body` tag. I assume this has something to do with it defaulting to quirks mode without the DOCTYPE, but what am I doing wrong that might be invalid CSS? (I've validated with jigsaw and it doesn't show any errors/warnings.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you were missing the DOCTYPE — which really should have been there to begin with — your page was being rendered in quirks mode. In quirks mode, browsers are known to stretch the height of `body` to 100% of the height of the viewport. In standards mode, which is triggered by having an appropriate DOCTYPE, `body` behaves like a regular block-level element, being only as tall as its contents by default. In your case, this results in `body`'s background color not being visible.

There's nothing inherently wrong with your CSS, which is why it validates, but if you want `body` to stretch to the height of the viewport in standards mode, you should add the following height properties to `html` and `body` respectively:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```