# <doctype html> is messing up my CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, doctype

In a nutshell, i want a `right div float` to extend vertically `100%` 
but it only works when i don't include `<doctype>` on my html

in today's standard, do i really have to add `<doctype>`?

This is the result in Internet Explorer:

[image: doctype issues]

this is just simple `html`

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrap {
background:red;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#left {
background:yellow;
float:left;
width:70%;
min-height:100%;
}
#right {
background:pink;
float:right;
width:30%;
min-height:100%;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="left"> Content </div>
<div id="right"> Side Content </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only if you want valid markup.... Please post the entirety of the HTML and CSS.

Comment: would it hurt my site if i dont use it?

Comment: If by "hurt" you mean "increase the likelihood of a browser mangling the markup", then yes.

Comment: Yes, it will. Your impression that it "messes up your CSS" is not in line with the standards, which is the real problem at hand.

Comment: please post a demo on jsfiddle.net. from what you've posted so far, we can't tell what the error is.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't think you can force quirks mode in jsFiddle.

Comment: Yes, I believe that jsFiddle wraps the HTML in a doctype, but that'll at least let us see where any potential bugs may lie.

Comment: @user1735120 - Looks fine to me (after separating the HTML and CSS to their separate windows): http://jsfiddle.net/jackmaney/QyrLn/ If you're seeing the issue that you originally reported, then something else is causing it.

Comment: @Jeff: This is an IE issue - see the link in my comment on Tim's answer.

Comment: im testing this in chrome. and id like to point out that this causes errors too.

Comment: doctype makes things case-sensible including the name of your id and classes and might explain why doctype mess-up your css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> in today's standard, do i really have to add `<doctype>`?

You don't **have** to do anything, but the absence of the DOCTYPE is essentially asserting that you conform (in the loosest sense of the term) to an unknown/inconsistent "quirks" standard.

I imagine the solution is as simple as setting the height of the parent container to 100% or to a specific pixel height.

- ensure that height is set on the `HTML` and `BODY` elements.
- ensure that height is set on any parent containers.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7xxFj/

```
<div id="one">
    First column
</div>
<div id="two">
    second column
</div>​

HTML, BODY { height: 100%; }
#one { height: 100%; width: 30%; float: left; background-color: red; }
#two { height: 100%; width: 70%; float: left; background-color: blue; }
```

As @BoltClock pointed out in the comments, you probably want a layout that can extend beyond 100%. This requires a little more effort (but still works well within the standard).

[This article](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) shows several methods for accomplishing layouts with equal column heights. More [methods here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks).

Comment: Yep. You'll want to set only a `min-height: 100%` on the BODY element so it stretches when content overflows down the viewport, of course. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125961/background-color-property-doesnt-work-correctly-with-html5-doctype/12126106#12126106) where I address basically the same issue (and explain just what exactly is going on).

Comment: Ha...now I'm having trouble getting it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/7xxFj/3/. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Oh, that. Getting the columns to be equal height is a different issue altogether I'm afraid...

Comment: Okay, I'll post links/solution for an equal height layout; just checking that I wasn't doing something stupid.

Comment: thanks for answering my question; im also dealing with the issue having equal column height;

Comment: @user1735120 - equal height columns aren't too bad...the links I posted should help. Equal height columns which are exactly 100% aren't too bad either. Equal height columns which are 100% minimum height but expand indefinitely and equally are difficult. I couldn't find a simple solution for that where the columns are truly the same height. If you don't find a solution, post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking of considering IE (any version for that matter, lets not digress to this topic), then you are better of specifying the DOCTYPE. I have seen many pages which do not do this properly through IE into the famous Quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrap {
background:red;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#right {
background:blue;
float:left;
width:30%;
height:100%;
}
#left {
background:yellow;
float:left;
width:70%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="left"> Content </div>
<div id="right"> Side Content </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By using the doctype that you suggest here removed the error for me. However, Chrome's Lighthouse Audit tool considers the Doctype to be missing.