# Chrome Web App webview height issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm new in Chrome Web App programming. I want a simple WebApp which is separated to my Chrome/Chromium (means no tab). It shall show a external website in the body.

So here is my configuration:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My first Chrome App.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [ "webview" ],
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    bounds: {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 600
    }
  });
});
```

window.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <webview style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://www.google.de"></webview>
  </body>
</html>
```

I excpected a window like this (it shows Chromium for demonstraiton):
[image]

But I got these:

[image]

So the height in webview isn't correct. When I set the height to (for example) 192px, it's show the correct size. But 100% isn't working...

Comment: I'm not very [good at CSS](https://s3.amazonaws.com/firebelly/blog-posts/graphics/171/original/css_is_awesome.gif), but can you try setting the same style also to `<body>`/`<html>`? (easier in a style file than inline)

Comment: Hi @Xan that wasn't working. I have answered my question by myself now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28209572/1231245

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've asked [François Beaufort](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts) (Chromium engineer atm) on Google+.
Hey replayed:

> The chromium team uses window.onresize to recalculate webview width
>   and height in this sample:
>   https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/webview-samples/browser/browser.js

After looking on these example I have the following Chrome App.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My first Chrome App.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [ "webview" ],
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    bounds: {
      'width': 1050,
      'height': 700
    }
  });
});
```

window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <webview src='http://www.google.de' id="xx"></webview>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js (here is the magic :D)

```
function updateWebviews() {
  var webview = document.querySelector("webview");
  webview.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight + "px";
  webview.style.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth + "px";
};

onload = updateWebviews;
window.onresize = updateWebviews;
```

Now I have exactly what I want. A webview with fullscreen of a web page:
[image]

**Edit:**

I've also uploaded a git repo on GitHub for see the SourceCode:
https://github.com/StefMa/ChromeAppWebsite

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me (within a style element in the HTML obviously):

```
webview {
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution seems to work for me, it's not ideal, but works:

```
<webview src="https://github.com" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;"></webview>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could happen because you are using relative height and width with `<!DOCTYPE html>`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734812/doctype-html-prevents-relative-css-heights) for an explanation.

Instead of using 100%, you could try specifying the width and height in pixels.

```
<webview style="display:block; width:400px; height:600px;" src="http://www.google.de"></webview>
```

Comment: It is working with specific pixels. But that wasn't what I want.

Comment: @StefMa your answer is much better!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to styles.css

```
webview{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```