# Dynamically created webview not filling the space

Tags: javascript, three.js, google-chrome-app

I'm building a Chrome Packaged App with WebGL and Three.js, with the goal of making a prototype for a 3-D browser. I am using the CSS3D renderer to render a dynamically-created `webview` element onto a Three.js plane surface. I've gotten this to work when creating an `iframe` element, but when I use a `webview`, I get the following result:

[image: Notice how it doesn't fill the space]

The code I'm using to create the webview is:

```
var webview = document.createElement('webview');
webview.setAttribute('src', 'url erased to protect identity');
webview.style.width = '100%';
webview.style.height = '100%';
element.appendChild(webview);
```

Where `element` is a `div` element that is properly scaled to fit on the plane.

How do I make the `webview` element stretch to fill the parent `div`?

**EDIT:** The method displayed in the answer to [Chrome webview height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194413) had no visible effect for me.

**EDIT 2:** I looked at the answer to [Why can't I make my div 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871898/why-cant-i-make-my-div-100-height-if-i-use-an-html5-doctype-how-do-i-get-it-1) and looked at it. The really curious thing is that it's not even obvious from the developer tools why it's not working. Here's a screenshot of the developer tools showing the page:

[image: Apparently Chrome thinks it's taking that whole space?]

It looks to me like Chrome thinks the `webview` is taking that whole space. I honestly don't understand what's going on here. Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: get the dimensions of the `element` and assign them to `webview`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Web App webview height issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194413/chrome-web-app-webview-height-issue)

Comment: You should look into the root of the problem (HTML5 100% height). Feel free to edit/comment if that still does not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I make my div 100% height if I use an HTML5 doctype? How do I get it 100% height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871898/why-cant-i-make-my-div-100-height-if-i-use-an-html5-doctype-how-do-i-get-it-1)

Comment: @Xan: edited. It's really odd...I can't seem to make the developer tools tell me what's wrong.