# HTML5 maintains aspect ratio of images?

Tags: html, css

I just noticed that Chrome resizes this image **keeping its aspect ratio**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="image.jpg">
```

When the HTML5 doctype isn't there, the image is distorted:

```
<img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="image.jpg">
```

This only works when the image's container is the document, it doesn't work if the image is in a `div` for example.

What is this feature, and can I somehow scale the image to the full window size without removing the doctype?

Comment: Got a codepen demo or other link demoing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you ever not have `html` and `body` tags? I assume chrome does that in order to display nicely if you only have an image or it is an unintended sideefect from an invalid html. Anyways since that is invalid html, you won't find an answer that will always and reliably work.

Comment: @Geuis I mean a SO-code snippet would be the close choice, but I don't know any program that just lets you write that and doesn't add the whole `<html><head>…</head><body></body></html>`-stuff

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Do you want an image that will expand to the full size of the page?

Comment: Actually `html` and `body` don't make a difference, they can be there and the aspect ratio is still maintained. I'll add them to the example to make that clear.

Comment: @Geuis Yes, I want an image that will expand to the full size of the page.

Comment: @SourceOverflow: "Why would you ever not have html and body tags?" Because they just add unnecessary bloat and leaving them out isn't invalid? (The asker's edit, adding 8 completely unnecessary lines to their otherwise short and sweet examples, demonstrates this perfectly.)

Comment: Both codepen and SO snippets seem to add an HTML5 doctype, so I cannot replicate the second case there.

Comment: What happens when you feed chrome valid HTML5? (use validator.w3.org to make your code HTML5 valid)

Comment: @Code4R7: Are you implying that the markup is invalid? Other than a missing title element and alt attribute - two very minor issues that don't impact rendering at all - I don't see what is so wrong with the markup that's been given.

Comment: @BoltClock The html and body tags are required under certain circumstances as outlined in the spec.

Comment: @Rob: Certainly not here.

Comment: "A body element’s start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the body element is not a space character or a comment, except if the first thing inside the body element is a meta, link, script, style, or template element." https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#the-body-element @BoltClock It's possible the first character here is a new line but it might not be.

Comment: @Rob: That just means that if you want the newline to be part of the body element, you need to place a start tag at the end of the previous line. Otherwise, the newline is treated as inter-element whitespace and discarded (i.e. not part of the body element's content). In this case, it doesn't make any difference to rendering because whitespace in inlines gets collapsed due to `white-space: normal` anyway. As far as CSS is concerned, the only boxes that exist are html, body, img, and the line box that contains the img.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Yes, but as I've pointed out, it has zero impact on rendering. I wouldn't object to an edit adding in a title, but I wouldn't kick up a fuss about it either.

Comment: @BoltClock You are right, and adding just a title element while not adding the alt attr would not make it into a valid HTML doc. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This "feature" is exclusive to quirks mode, in which `html` and `body` have 100% height, and the heights of top-level elements are made relative to `body`. In standards mode, `html` and `body` act as regular block boxes with auto heights. Since a percentage height cannot be relative to an auto height, `height: 100%` doesn't take effect and the image keeps its aspect ratio in standards mode.

This is also why [`body` backgrounds display fully in quirks mode, but not in standards mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125961/body-background-color-property-doesnt-work-correctly-with-html5-doctype/12126106#12126106), when there isn't enough content to fill the page.

To get the quirks-mode behavior in standards mode, set `height: 100%` on the `html` element and `min-height: 100%` on the `body` element as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682/height-100-or-min-height-100-for-html-and-body-elements/17555766#17555766).

Comment: For new web pages, of course, there should never be a reason to be in quirks mode or want to emulate it.

Comment: Of course not. Different browsers have different quirks too.

Comment: @Rob: Agreed, though I wouldn't call this emulating quirks mode. This is just replicating specific quirks in standards mode because their behavior is desired.

Comment: It seems I was a bit quick to accept this answer. The reasoning makes sense, but the remedy doesn't work: `<!doctype html><html style="height: 100%;"><body style="min-height: 100%;"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="https://placekitten.com/400/200?image=1"></body></html>` does not result in the quirks-mode behavior (Chrome 63).

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzLrjw

```
body {
  background: url('http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300'); 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Not ideal because I already have code that works with images, like attaching onload handlers to them, which I would have to maintain twice. Actually I don't even know how to attach an onload handler to a background image.